# VBA send email using Gmail: transport failed to connect

Tags: vba, excel, gmail, cdo.message

Running the Excel VBA code below I get the following error:

> Run-time error -2147220973
>   The transport failed to connect to the server

```
Public Function send_email()

Set cdomsg = CreateObject("CDO.message")
With cdomsg.Configuration.Fields
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'NTLM method
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smptserverport") = 465
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 10
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "mymail@gmail.com"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "mypass"
.Update
End With
' build email parts
With cdomsg
.To = "mymail@gmail.com"
.From = "mymail@gmail.com"
.Subject = "the email subject"
.TextBody = "the full message body goes here. you may want to create a variable to hold the text"
.Send
End With
    Set cdomsg = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Try using port 587 instead of 465

Comment: It did not work

Answer (score 0):

## Trouble source

A **typo** caused this mess - **smptserverport** should be **smtpserverport**!

## Things I tried

On the way to solve this issue, I tried many things. But now I'm not so sure if all were actually needed.
still, someone might gain something from the list:

- Enable "[Less Secure App](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)"
- Open "[Display Captcha](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)" before testing connection
- Make sure you have a strong password
- [App Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) are no longer recommended
- [2 Step Verification](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/) is not a must - but highly recommended!

## Few tips:

- Port **465** should be in use when sending the password in **clear text**
- Port **587** should be used when sending a **secure password**.

if you need to have secure password within VBA/VBS, you can use this little trick with PowerShell ([source](https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25162)):

```
Dim myPassword, cmd, shell, executor, securePassword
myPassword = "ABCABCABC....."
cmd = "powershell.exe ConvertTo-SecureString "& myPassword
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set executor = shell.Exec(cmd)
executor.StdIn.Close
securePassword = executor.StdOut.ReadAll
```

Answer (score -1):

Now I am using the bellow code and it works fine.
Don't forget to change your gmail config to allow sending email from other apps.

```
Sub sendEmail(gmail, password, targetEmail, subject, bodyContent)

    Dim Mail As New Message
    Dim Config As Configuration: Set Config = Mail.Configuration

    Config(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
    Config(cdoSMTPServer) = "smtp.gmail.com"
    Config(cdoSMTPServerPort) = 465
    Config(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoBasic
    Config(cdoSMTPUseSSL) = True
    Config(cdoSendUserName) = gmail
    Config(cdoSendPassword) = password
    Config.Fields.Update

    Mail.To = targetEmail
    Mail.from = Config(cdoSendUserName)
    Mail.subject = subject
    Mail.HTMLBody = bodyContent

    Mail.Send

End Sub
```